# Write a Move command that will copy the last 32 bytes of the Code segment to location 1000 in the Data segment

Tags: microprocessors

1. Write a Move command that will copy the last 32 bytes of the Code segment to
   location 1000 in the Data segment.
2. What is the minimum and maximum number of bytes that can be moved using the
   Move command?

Comment: We're not your personal coursework-completion service. We *can* help you if you can deomnstrate a bare-minimum, good-faith attempt at answering the questions as they're posed here (while being mindful of including all the context necessary to answer the question in the first place) by providing the code you've already written as a [mre] along with a succinct explanation of where you're getting stuck. Please familiarize yourself with [ask] and edit your question to conform to the guidance therein.

Comment: Tangentially, you should also understand that posting your academic coursework here for others to complete on your behalf (especially with no discernible effort on your part) is a blatant violation of academic ethics and integrity, and likely falls afoul of your institution's policies on such matters. Penalties for violations of these codes of conduct generally carry extremely steep penalties. For your own sake, please re-evaluate your post and whether or not you're willing to accept such a risk to your academic career for a post such as this one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.